# Generate same password using bcrypt package nodejs

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package to generate encrypt passwords. I am using the code below to encrypt the password:

```
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
```

It returns different hash for same password. But my requirement is that I need same hash for same password. Please let me is it possible using bcrypt package. If not please suggest me different package that I can use?

**EDIT:**
I am using [oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-server) package. And with this package I am generation token. So in this package there is no way to compare the hash. As that work is handled internally by the package. So I am looking for package that can give me same hash.

Comment: Why do you need the same hash?

Comment: @AbhyuditJain That is what my requirement is. I am comparing the hash as stored in database.

Comment: I would say, that might not be the correct approach. I am not sure about the exact requirement though, but being different hash every time is what I've seen so far. Why do you need to compare stored hashed password in db ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bcrypt generates different hashes for the same input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467819/bcrypt-generates-different-hashes-for-the-same-input)

Comment: @agpt.. Updated question

Comment: @TavishAggarwal You should get user's password in login api all, verify it using bcrypt.verify and then if it's verified, geenrate token.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal, why you are thinking to compare your hashed password with `==` method ? Try instead `bycrypt.compare()` method. They can compare your password as well.