# Creating password hash in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash

I created user and I gave him password 'secret'.
The hash that was generated by the registration process is

```
$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm
```

I wanted to generate it in the code so I used Hash::make('secret') and I got:

```
$2y$10$Hnbg7DCp2VObns4cbr580uo9VTYgzJF2BSNSpA7S8BYjkAgfUlH.G
```

finally I used bcrypt('secret') and I got:

```
 $2y$10$5g1bhkHB7kRk8SkM3yS/YOifsEesjZ31YeYnRlE.bxSBmZutVCuui
```

These are all different hashes, How can I generate one that would let me change password inside my code?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It's because bcrypt doesn't work as SHA-256, it uses a key that would change the result of the hash itself for the same string.
In Laravel, you can use `Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)` to check the password, but you will never have the same result for the same password. check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing#basic-usage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bcrypt(secret") and leave it at laravel and test it (everything is working).

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended, bcrypt doesnt always generate the same hash. Laravels `Hash::check()` function will return true for any valid hash of the given password.

For mor informations, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468936/6622577

Answer (score 0):

Bycrypt is a more secure password hashing algorithm. Unlike md5() or SHA1() bycrypt does not always generate the same hashed value for a specific string.

So when you are storing the hashed password in the database you will use

```
$password = bcrypt($input['password']);
```

Afterwards, when you wish to check at the time of login you simply set the plain-text password (As you might be getting it from user input) and run a function called Auth::attempt() to match the password.

```
$userdata = array(
    'username'      => $input['username'],
    'password'      => $input['password'],
);


if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    // Password matched
}
```

And if you want to explicitly check the plain-text password corresponding to its hash then use Hash::check() as below:

```
Hash::check('plain-text-password', 'hashed-password);
```